# Altering just part of a Mat in real-time video OpenCV Native C++ Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm attempting to use native Opencv code in android-studio to detect a face in real-time and then create a new rectangular Mat around the facial region and change the color scheme to black and white.

I've succeeded in altering the entire Mat except for the box i wanted which leads me to believe that I'm close to achieving my goal, yet I can't seem to figure out the changes i need to make to the code.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_facedetect_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeRGB
    (JNIEnv *jenv, jlong image, jdouble x1, jdouble y1, jdouble x2, jdouble y2){

Mat *img = (Mat*) image;
cvtColor(*img,*img,CV_GRAY2RGB);

Point p1(x1+100,y1+100);
Point p2(x2,y2);
Rect roi(p1, p2);


Mat img_uv;
//Change entire mat to YUV
cvtColor(*img, img_uv, CV_RGB2YUV);

//YUV 3 channels
vector<Mat> channels(3);
split(img_uv, channels);

Mat Y = channels[0];
Mat U = channels[1];
Mat V = channels[2];

Mat mask = Mat::zeros(Y.size(), Y.type());
rectangle(mask, roi, Scalar(1), CV_FILLED);

// merge channels
channels[0] = Y;
channels[1] = U.mul(mask)+(Scalar::all(1)-mask).mul(Y);
channels[2] = V.mul(mask)+(Scalar::all(1)-mask).mul(Y);
Mat img_yuv_out;
merge(channels, img_yuv_out);
cvtColor(img_yuv_out, *img, CV_YUV2RGB);
}
```

[image: Output]

The above is the JNI method im using. The java code creates the Mat and is passed onto the above method as a jlong. I've attempted to simply change the color of the mask as follows

```
cvtColor(mask(roi), mask(roi), CV_RBG2GRAY);
```

After the code executes i then reuse the originally used Mat in the java code. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

but that caused the program to crash.

Comment: It is a little unclear. So you want to keep the inner box (face) black and white. What will happen to the rest of the mat(outer - inner box)? Also do u read the video as gray scale?

Comment: I'm reading the video in normal RGB, and my goal is to create a new Mat that is the same Mat with my facial region transformed in any way, like the @Nejc image shows.

Comment: @user3160152 Does my answer cover everything you wanted to know or did I miss something?

Comment: Hey, it didnt work since I need to pass the mat as a (Mat *) from java to c++, so I couldnt use img(roi) :/

Comment: @user3160152 - I changed the code example so that it more closely resembles your code. Can you make it work now? :)

Comment: I'll test it out, thank you for all your patience!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you convert a part of image to grayscale:

```
Mat img = imread("Lenna.png");

Mat *image = &img;

Rect roi = Rect(100, 100, 100, 100);

Mat gray;
cvtColor((*image)(roi), gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
Mat gray_3ch;
cvtColor(gray, gray_3ch, CV_GRAY2RGB);

gray_3ch.copyTo((*image)(roi));
```

[image]

**Edit:** To help the author of the question, I changed the Mat with pointer to Mat in the code example. The only reason why I did that is so that he will be able to make his code work right.